# AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Mars giving error while startup

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have installed AWS Toolkit on my Eclipse Mars. When I restarted my Eclipse, it is giving me below error. Any idea about this issue?

"Internal error when starting the AWS Toolkit plugin.
Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified."

[image]

I tried to configure AWS ToolKit preference. But that page is coming blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was caused by AWS Access Id and Secret Key not setup. 
You can  delete the C:\users\uername\.aws folder and restart the eclipse, it would ask you again to put in the credential.